# What's a good solution to drop nil value in a struct for Elixir?

Tags: elixir

For example, I have a struct

```
post = %Post{title: "Title", desc: nil}
```

And I want to get

```
%{title: "Title"}
```

My solution is like

```
post
  |> Map.delete(:__struct__) # change the struct to a Map
  |> Enum.filter(fn {_, v} -> v end)
  |> Enum.into(%{})
```

It works, but is there a better one?

*Update*:

I feel it annoying transforming from Struct to Map, then Enum, then Map again. Is there a concise way?

Comment: Not very clear what you're asking - better how? One thing I would change is use `Map.from_struct` instead of `Map.delete(...)`

Comment: Thanks, I feel it annoying transforming from Struct to Map, then Enum, then Map. Is there a concise way?

Comment: @Tony your solution is ok I think, but it has a flaw: It will also discard entries where the value is `false`. You need to change the filtering to `Enum.filter(fn {_, v} -> v != nil end)` or `Enum.reject(fn {_, v} -> v == nil end)`

Comment: Isn't this something `Jason` or `Poison` can handle?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
post
  |> Map.delete(:__struct__) # change the struct to a Map
  |> Enum.filter(fn {_, v} -> v end)
  |> Enum.into(%{})
```

You can do

```
post
  |> Map.from_struct
  |> Enum.filter(fn {_, v} -> v != nil end)
  |> Enum.into(%{})
```

It's just slightly cleaner than deleting the `__struct__` key manually.

Comment: You should change the filtering in the second example to either `v != nil` or use `reject` instead of `filter`.

Comment: Btw, StackOverflow uses four spaces indentation to format code blocks, backticks are only for inline code. Edited your answer.

Comment: I accepts this answer because I can't figure out a better way and the comprehensions solution is a little difficult to read.

Comment: You could use the terse, using the anonymous function shorthand: `|> Enum.filter(&(&1))`

Answer (score 26):

You could also do this with comprehensions:

```
for {k, v} <- Map.from_struct(post), v != nil, into: %{}, do: {k, v}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is inspired!

Comment: Three years later, still a hot answer.

Answer (score 7):

Also can be written like this:

```
post
    |> Map.from_struct
    |> Enum.reject(fn {_, v} -> is_nil(v) end)
    |> Map.new
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
post
  |> Map.from_struct()
  |> Enum.filter(fn {_key, value} -> !is_nil(value) end)
  |> Map.new()
```

`Map.new/1` is thought exactly to convert a keyword list into a map.